# Can't run Unity3d, can't create the ALF for the manual license activation

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, license-key

I installed Unity 2021.3.11f1 on Windows 11, but when I run the editor it says "No valid Unity Editor license found. Please activate your license." So I tried to do [these instructions][1] to activate my license.

However, after running "unity.exe -batchmode -createManualActivationFile -logfile", I can't find the Activation License File (ALF) anyhwere, be it C:/Users/Naburu38, C:\ProgramData\Unity, C:\Users\Naburu38\AppData\Local\Unity, or C:\Users\Naburu38\AppData\LocalLow\Unity.

I run the CMD both as regular and admin. I checked my admin account folders too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running this in a VM?

Comment: No, I'm not.

(extra characters)

Comment: alternatively you can instead try and use plain `-username` and `-password` of your Unity account ... I see though why this is not really a preferable solution ... but I used this in the past to make it work ... or simply use the Hub and login there to activate the license (https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/Manual/ManualActivationGuide.html#alf-commandline)

Comment: The path would be the path where your console was at the moment when you ran that command ... usually by default your home user folder (e.g. `C:\Users\You`)